# Changing fonts in grafana 6.7.2 and 7.0

Tags: fonts, visualization, grafana

I´m trying to use Grafana Dashboards at work and I would like to customise my panels more, in terms of changing Text/ Title colors and fonts. I managed to change the Title color and size, but only for all of the panels at the same time. I need to be able to customize each panel sperately.

Has anyone an idea to do it? I´m still quite new to this : )